# Absolute position div inside an absolute position div. How does it work if the outer div isn't position: relative?

Tags: html, css, position

For my understanding, if we do the following:

```
<div id="Outer">
    <div id="Inner"></div>
</div>
```

The outer div position is relative and the inner one's position is absolute, then we would be able to position the inner one wherever we want basically inside the "Outer div" (top / left / bottom etc').

In my attempts to figure out how the position element works, i've tried setting up the following build:

1. Outer div.
2. Inner div inside the outer div.
3. inner div inside the inner div.

What i did change was the position of the inner div to absolute, and even thou the inner inner div was absolute and its parent was absolute, i was still able to position the inner inner div. I'm trying to understand how and why I was able to do that. I mean, the parent div (div number 2) => isn't position: relative; but it is position: absolute; and yet, I've successfully positioned the inner inner div just like you would position when the parent is position: relative.

Would be happy to hear explanation as for why this specific setup worked.
Here is the complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.OuterDiv {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.InnerDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #D3DEEF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.InnerInner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="OuterDiv">
    <div class="InnerDiv">
        <div class="InnerInner">Inner Inner</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `position: absolute;` element will be positioned relative to it's parent element if the parent element's position is **not** static. (It can be absolute, relative etc, but not static)